# Elastic bool-query inside filter-query has always zero score

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a weird problem with my elastic query which I'm not able to figure out. I'm quite fresh to Elastic.

I have the following query to search through my index:

```js
GET frow_local_commerce_master_a1/product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "commercialCode",
            "query": "*UE1406* OR UE1406~",
            "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
            "fuzziness": 2,
            "default_operator": "OR",
            "boost": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*UE1406*",
            "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
            "fields": [
              "range^2.0"
            ],
            "default_operator": "OR"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "localized",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "*UE1406*",
                "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                "fields": [
                  "localized.floorType^2.0",
                  "localized.productName^3.0"
                ],
                "default_operator": "OR"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected. No problems at all, but the problem is that whenever I expand this main query with a filter query:

```js
GET frow_local_commerce_master_a1/product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "brand.keyword": {
              "value": "QS"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "commercialCode",
                    "query": "*UE1406* OR UE1406~",
                    "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                    "fuzziness": 2,
                    "default_operator": "OR",
                    "boost": 100
                  }
                },
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "*UE1406*",
                    "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                    "fields": [
                      "range^2.0"
                    ],
                    "default_operator": "OR"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "localized",
                    "query": {
                      "query_string": {
                        "query": "*UE1406*",
                        "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                        "fields": [
                          "localized.floorType^2.0",
                          "localized.productName^3.0"
                        ],
                        "default_operator": "OR"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "localized.language.keyword": {
                        "value": "nl-BE"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "path": "localized"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see this query is identical as the first query, but has a "query" -> "filter" above it. I need this because I need to filter on other attributes aswell next to my main search query.

**The problem** is that this query always has a _score 0. Whenever I run the first query, I have a normal score..

Does anyone have any idea why my _score is always zero when I execute the second query? And what can possibly be the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Queries written in [`Filter Context`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context) do not participate in scoring process. i.e for filter queries you won't get any scores. `Filter Queries` are mainly used to filter structured data.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the explanation. Any idea on which other approach I should take to do the same but with scoring?

Comment: Its simple, just move those queries into `query context`. Please go through the url mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Makes sense now, thank you for the explanation.